# Why $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is open in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)$?

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory, locally-compact-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. Denote by $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\mathbb Z_p$ the field of $p$-adic numbers and the ring of $p$-adic integers. Why $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is open in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ ?

Comment: Why do you think it is?

Comment: Define the determinant map $\text{det}: \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p) \to \mathbb{Q}_p$. then $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)=\{A \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p ~|~ \text{det}(A)=1 \}$. The map $\text{det}$ is given by a polynomial with coefficient in $M_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, which is continuous

Comment: @Adayah I saw it in George Willis lecture notes on totally disconnected locally compact groups, and in other texts as an  ordinary fact.

Comment: Perhaps open in $SL(2, \mathbb{Q}_p)$ ?  That is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not open: consider the identity matrix $I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and any basic open neighborhood $$U_n = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1+\varepsilon_1 & \varepsilon_2 \\ \varepsilon_3 & 1+\varepsilon_4 \end{pmatrix} : v_p(\varepsilon_i) \geqslant n \text{ for } i = 1, 2, 3, 4 \right\} \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p).$$

Then $A_n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & p^n \\ p^n & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is in the neighborhood but not in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, so $U_n \not \subseteq \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you are right, I think it was a typo in chapter 9 of the book "New directions in locally compact groups".

Comment: A typo means a typographic error. A wrong assertion is, by definition, not a typo (though it can be unimportant in some cases). Possibly the author indeed meant to say it's open in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$?